# Geolocation Android significant delay in response

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Requesting location permissions behaves normally on iOS, returning a successful response immediately. But on Android, the response return time seems to be correlated with the timeout value. ie if my timeout is set to 20000, I get the response 20 seconds after I allow permission. Similarly, when I set it to 1000, the coords are return in 1 second.

Anyone else experienced this before?

Here is my code:

```
requestLocation = () => {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        console.log("lat: ", position.coords.latitude,
          "long: ", position.coords.longitude);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("you do not have permissions");
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 10000
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: It's worth looking into whether or not the devices you are testing on are Oreo or higher, because if they are, this may be impacting it: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits